# Using DTC and for repeated Single Channel Reading on MSP430

Tags: adc, msp430

I'm trying to use the DTC to continuously update a variable without CPU intervention. However I am not getting any results and cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the method to initialize the DTC:

```
void initializeDTC(unsigned int channel,unsigned int *pointer){
    // Disable ADC before configuration.
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;

    // Turn ADC on in single line before configuration.
    ADC10CTL0 = ADC10ON;

    // Set channel, Use SMCLK, 1/8 Divider, Repeat single channel.
    ADC10CTL1 = channel | ADC10SSEL_3 | ADC10DIV_7 | CONSEQ_2;
    // 0 clock ticks, Use Reference, Reference on, ADC On, Multi-Sample Conversion, Interrupts enabled.
    ADC10CTL0 |= ADC10SHT_1 | SREF_1 | REFON | MSC;

    // Put results at specified place in memory.
    ADC10SA = (int)pointer;
    // Only one conversion at a time.
    ADC10DTC1 = 0x01;
    // Repeat conversion.
    ADC10DTC0 = ADC10CT;

    // Start conversion.
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC | ADC10SC;
    // I've read that trying to start the conversion twice is necessary.
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC | ADC10SC;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
unsigned int temperature;
initializeDTC(INCH_10,&temperature);
// Do stuff with temperature in a loop.
```

If I've understood the documentation correctly, after each conversion the ADC should start the next conversion because of the `MSC` bit. At the same time the DTC should transfer the value of `ADC10MEM` to the value in address in `ADC10SA` (the value of my pointer). The value of my `temperature` variable remains at the default value of whatever was in the memory previously (35 thousand and something for me).

I considered the possibility of the DTC having not finished before the next conversion, but the documentation states that the DTC will take at most 4 `MCLK` cycles. In my application I `SMCLK`=`MCLK` and since the conversion takes 8 `SMCLK` cycles I should be fine in this respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The key was when configuring the DTC to set `ADC10SA` last. If you look at [Figure 22-10](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144i/slau144i.pdf#page=560&zoom=100,0,102.9) of the Users Guide you can see that setting `ADC10DTC1` moves the DTC from "Reset" to "Init" state so I would set `ADC10DTC0` before that. Then it waits for a write to `ADC10SA` before starting.

I also made some modifications to allow for easy switching between Sequence and Single channel modes. My final code looks like this:

```
void initializeDTC(unsigned int channel,unsigned int pointer[], bool sequence){

    // Disable ADC before configuration.
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;

    // Turn ADC on in single line before configuration.
    ADC10CTL0 = ADC10ON;

    // Make sure the ADC is not running per 22.2.7
    while(ADC10CTL1 & ADC10BUSY);

    // Repeat conversion.
    ADC10DTC0 = ADC10CT;
    // Only one conversion at a time.
    ADC10DTC1 = sequence ? channel >> 12 : 1;
    // Put results at specified place in memory.
    ADC10SA = ((unsigned int)pointer);

    // 8 clock ticks, Use Reference, Reference on, ADC On, Multi-Sample Conversion, Interrupts enabled.
    ADC10CTL0 |= ADC10SHT_1 | SREF_1 | REFON  | ADC10IE | MSC;
    // Set channel, Use SMCLK, 1/8 Divider, Repeat single channel.
    ADC10CTL1 = channel | ADC10SSEL_3 | ADC10DIV_7 | (sequence ? CONSEQ_3 : CONSEQ_2);

    // Enable conversion.
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC;
    // Start conversion
    ADC10CTL0 |= ADC10SC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
volatile unsigned int temperature;
```

The compiler might put the variable into a register otherwise, and will not read the updated memory location.

Comment: Well I can tell via debugging that it is not in a register (it's actually memory address 0x05DF), but I went ahead and tried the volatile keyword just in case. There was no difference.